# How to get Carbon instance from collection variable in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, date, laravel-5.1, php-carbon

there does any one know how to change collection variable into Corban diffForHumans instance... e.g.

```
    {!!  $item['date']->diffForHumans() !!}
```

it gives an error of Call to a member function diffForHumans() on string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just create the object on the fly with `Carbon::parse()`:

```
{{ Carbon::parse($item['date'])->diffForHumans() }}
```

Comment: this worked also {{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $item['date'])->diffForHumans() }}